# Batch operations with Mobile AWS SDK (Unity) and DynamoDB

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Mobile AWS SDK with Unity to store data in DynamoDB. It works well, but only writing one Document at a time (I have litterally thousands of Documents to store), which is make my application struggling.
The problem is that I found no documentation about Batch processing. Does anyone know how to implement Batch writing?

This is the code I use to write 1 item at a time:

```
foreach (var dataDocument in listOfDocuments)
{
    MyTable.PutItemAsync(dataDocument, (r) => { });
}
```

I have tried that:

```
private void LoadAWSTable1()
{
    DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
    DynamoDBOperationConfig config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig();
    config.SkipVersionCheck = true;
    var threadBatch = context.CreateBatchWrite<Thread>(config);
    threadBatch.ExecuteAsync();
    listOfDocuments.Clear();
}
```

But ExecuteAsync() give this error:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
> required formal parameter 'callback' of
> 'BatchWrite.ExecuteAsync(AmazonDynamoDBCallback, AsyncOptions)'

Thanks

Comment: If you're thinking of dumping large volumes of data onto DynamoDB, you could use Data Pipeline to import data from a CSV file to a table. However, you should be very careful about how thee data is repressed in the CSV file, as Data Pipeline is very particular about the format it reads.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error states `BatchWrite.ExecuteAsync` expects a parameter of type `Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBCallback`

You are not passing it in ...

```
threadBatch.ExecuteAsync(theCallbackDelegate, someAsyncOptions);
```

*Unfortunately I couldn't find this type in the Documentation, so I can't tell you the signature right now*

From the comments below I can only guess that at least the `someAsyncOptions` would be optional.

Actually the only thing I found was [`BatchWrite.ExecuteAsync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MBatchWriteExecuteAsyncCancellationToken.html) but not the one from your error ... might be a different version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I am very new to this. I am still getting the same error, I must put arguments to ExecuteAsync() function. Could you be more precise, please?

Comment: @NomansSkywalker oh sorry :D totally forgot to actually pass it in

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work as well. I have got this error:
"CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' to 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBCallback'". 
An idea?

Comment: oh ok so apparently you have some other version I didn't find any documentation for. But in the end it means: You have to pass in a callback delegate method that would probably be called when the async execute is done. Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation for this delegate type neither